# f is entire function such that $f(z)=-f(z+1)$ and $\mid f(z)\mid \leq e^{\pi |Im(z)|}$ then $f=c\sin (\pi z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose $f$ is entire such that $f(z+1)=-f(z)$ for all $z$ and $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq e^{\pi Im(z)}$ prove $f(z)=c\sin (\pi z)$.

First it is easy to show that $f(n)=0$ for all natural numbers and we need to use Liouville’s $$\frac{|f(z)|}{e^{\pi |Im(z)|}}\leq 1$$

But the denominator is not entire so I want to find a function which entire and have a bigger modulus value  I think it should be $\sin(\pi z)$. How to prove that $e^{\pi |Im(z)|}\leq |\sin(\pi z)|$.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, as it turns out, $|\sin(\pi z)| \le e^{\pi |\operatorname{Im}(z)|}$, but not (necessarily) the other way around!

Comment: @LutzL $f(0)=0, f(1)=-f(0)=9, f(2)=-f(1)=0$ and so on

Comment: I'm sorry, selective blindness strikes again. I'm sure I was looking for $f(0)=0$, but didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove $e^{\pi|\Im(z)|}\leq|\sin(\pi z)|$ because it isn't true, pick $z=0$ for example. But this approach can still work, so long as we choose our domains carefully.

Here's one way to do it: let $S$ be the vertical strip defined by $\Re(z)\in[-1/2,1/2]$. Define:
$$
g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}
$$
If we can show $g$ is bounded on $S$, then by the functional equation $f(z+1)=-f(z)$, we will have that $g$ is bounded on every vertical strip $\Re(z)\in[-1/2+k,1/2+k]$ by the same constant, so it will be bounded on all of $\mathbb{C}$ and thus constant.

Let's look at $\sin(x+iy)$:
$$
\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\sin(iy)\cos(x)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\sinh(y)\cos(x)
$$ 
Thus for $y$ large enough and some positive $C$:
$$
|\sin(x+iy)|^2 =(\sin(x)\cosh(y))^2+(\sinh(y)\cos(x))^2=\\
=\sin^2(x)(\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y))+\sinh^2(y)=\sin^2(x)+\sinh^2(y)>Ce^{-2|y|}
$$
So we get that for $\Im(z)$ large enough,
$$
|\sin(\pi z)|>C'e^{\pi|\Im(z)|}
$$
This means that $g$ is bounded on $S$ if we're far enough away from the origin:
$$
\left\vert\frac{f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}\right\vert<\left\vert\frac{f(z)}{C'e^{\pi\vert\Im(z)\vert}}\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{C'}
$$ 
Call the set where this holds $Z\subset S$. But the closure of $S-Z$ is compact and $g$ is continuous (it has a removable singularity at $0$), so it is also bounded there. Hence $g$ is bounded on $S$ and so $g$ is constant.

Comment: If it is not given that $c\sin \pi z$ is the answer, how can we determine $f$ with just the given conditions?

Comment: How do you mean? I never used the fact that $f(z)=c\sin(\pi z)$ in the proof of $f(z)=c\sin(\pi z)$.

Comment: I mean that, since you are asked to prove so, you are able to make a smart guess and define $g$. My question is, if you initially have completely no idea what $f$ is, how can you deduce the answer solely from the conditions?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you could try guessing that since only $y$ appears in the bound and due to $f(z)=-f(z+1)$, something periodic in the real direction might work. Then $\sin$ is probably the first option. Of course, hindsight is 20/20. In reality, it's probably a very difficult task.

Comment: Just figured out an approach to complete this task. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer here, just to demonstrate how to solve a slightly harder problem:

> An entire function $f$ satisfies the following conditions:
>
> 1. $f(0)=0$
> 2. $f(z+1)=-f(z)$
> 3. $|f(z)|\le \exp(\pi\cdot|\Im(z)|)$
>
> Find $f$.

---

The following theorems/identities will be used:

$$\frac{\Gamma(T+a)}{\Gamma(T)}\sim T^a \qquad(T\to\infty)$$
$$\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(a)=\frac\pi{\sin \pi a}$$
and [Hadamard factorization theorem (HFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem):

> If $f$ is an entire function of finite order $\rho$, and $\{c_n\}$ is the sequence of non-zero zeroes of $f$ repeated according to multiplicity, then
> $$f(z)=z^m e^{q(z)}\prod_{n=0}^\infty E_p\left(\frac z{c_n}\right)$$
> where $q$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $\rho$, and $p=[\rho]$.

---

### The order of $f$

$$\rho=\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\ln\ln \lVert f(z)\rVert_{\infty, |z|<r}}{\ln r}
\le\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\ln\ln e^{\pi r}}{\ln r}=1$$

Thus, $0\le\rho\le1$.

---

### Utilizing HFT

Let the sequence $\{a_n\}$ be the non-zero zeroes of $f$ on $\mathbb C$ repeated according to multiplicity.

Since $f(\mathbb Z)=0$, there is at least one sub-sequence $\{\cdots,-2,-1,1,2,\cdots\}$ in $\{a_n\}$. Let $\{b_n\}$ be the sequence $\{a_n\}-\{\mathbb Z_{\ne0}\}$ (removing one subsequence of non-zero integers).

By HFT,
$$f(z)=z^m e^{q(z)}\prod_{n=0}^\infty E_p\left(\frac z{b_n}\right)\cdot\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^N_{n=-N,n\ne 0}E_p\left(\frac zn\right)$$ where $m\ge 1$ (due to $f(0)=0$).

No matter $p=[\rho]=0$ or $1$, it can be shown that
$$f(z)=g_p(z)\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^N_{n=-N,n\ne 0}\left(1-\frac zn\right)$$
where $g_p$ is entire and has a zero at $z=0$.

---

### Obtaining Closed Form of Product Series

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^N_{n=-N,n\ne 0}\left(1-\frac zn\right)
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^N_{n=-N,n\ne 0}\frac{n-z}{n} \\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1{-z}\frac{\Gamma(N-z+1)}{\Gamma(-N-z)}\frac{(-1)^N}{\Gamma^2(N+1)} \\
\end{align}
$$

After applying Gamma reflection formula, we obtain
$$-\frac1z\lim_{N\to\infty}-\frac{\sin\pi z}\pi\frac{\Gamma(N-z+1)}{\Gamma(N+1)}\frac{\Gamma(N+z+1)}{\Gamma(N+1)} $$

which is asymptotic to
$$\sim\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}(N+1)^{-z}(N+1)^z\to \frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}$$

Therefore, $$f(z)=g_p(z)\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}:= h(z)\sin\pi z$$

Note that the singularity of $\frac{g_p(z)}{\pi z}$ at $0$ is removable and thus $h(z)$ is entire.

---

### Applying Liouville Theorem

Using condition 3 again, we obtain
$$|h(z)|\le\left\vert\frac{\exp(\pi|\Im(z)|)}{\sin\pi z}\right\vert$$

As shown in @J_P's answer, RHS is bounded for sufficiently large $\Im(z)$. Call this region $Z$. Moreover, @J_P showed that $h$ is bounded on $\mathbb C\setminus Z$ due to continuity and periodicity of $f$.

Hence, $h(z)$ is entire and bounded on $\mathbb C$. By Liouville theorem, $h(z)\equiv c$.

As a result, $$f(z)=c\sin\pi z$$

Comment: Nice work, it's a bit above my level though. Does the fact that $g_p$ is entire follow in some way from HFT or is it entire just because every product over isolated zeros is (is it, I don't know...)?

Comment: @J_P You can’t find any singularities in $g_p$, therefore...

Comment: I'm more unsure about convergence, if you pull out the product over all the real zeroes does the rest still converge everywhere, is the order important etc. Basically, I'm not familiar with when such infinite products actually converge. It's probably too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: @J_P Elementary factors converge to $1$ sufficiently fast so convergence is not an issue. Indeed, it is a basic theorem that the order of zeroes does not matter in a Hadamard product.

Comment: Ah, ok. If I understand correctly, the converse isn't necessarily true: if I come up with a bunch of zeroes in $\mathbb{C}$ and define a product of some elementary factors over them, the resulting product will not necessarily converge everywhere since there may be "too many zeroes" in the vicinity of a point (even if all the zeros are isolated). However, if my made-up set of zeroes does not have an accumulation point, am I guaranteed convergence?